# Panda's DataFrame - renaming multiple identically named columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have several columns named the same in a df. I need to rename them but the problem is that the `df.rename` method renames them all the same way. How I can rename the below blah(s) to blah1, blah4, blah5?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*5).reshape(2,5))
df.columns = ['blah','blah2','blah3','blah','blah']
df

#     blah  blah2  blah3  blah  blah
# 0   0     1      2      3     4
# 1   5     6      7      8     9
```

Here is what happens when using the `df.rename` method:

```
df.rename(columns={'blah':'blah1'})

#     blah1  blah2  blah3  blah1  blah1
# 0   0      1      2      3      4
# 1   5      6      7      8      9
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was looking to find a solution within Pandas more than a general Python solution.
Column's get_loc() function returns a masked array if it finds duplicates with 'True' values pointing to the locations where duplicates are found. I then use the mask to assign new values into those locations. In my case, I know ahead of time how many dups I'm going to get and what I'm going to assign to them but it looks like df.columns.get_duplicates() would return a list of all dups and you can then use that list in conjunction with get_loc() if you need a more generic dup-weeding action

**'''UPDATED AS-OF SEPT 2020'''**

```
cols=pd.Series(df.columns)
for dup in df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)]: 
    cols[df.columns.get_loc(dup)] = ([dup + '.' + str(d_idx) 
                                     if d_idx != 0 
                                     else dup 
                                     for d_idx in range(df.columns.get_loc(dup).sum())]
                                    )
df.columns=cols

    blah    blah2   blah3   blah.1  blah.2
 0     0        1       2        3       4
 1     5        6       7        8       9
```

**New Better Method (Update 03Dec2019)**

This code below is better than above code. Copied from another answer below (@SatishSK):

```
#sample df with duplicate blah column
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*5).reshape(2,5))
df.columns=['blah','blah2','blah3','blah','blah']
df

# you just need the following 4 lines to rename duplicates
# df is the dataframe that you want to rename duplicated columns

cols=pd.Series(df.columns)

for dup in cols[cols.duplicated()].unique(): 
    cols[cols[cols == dup].index.values.tolist()] = [dup + '.' + str(i) if i != 0 else dup for i in range(sum(cols == dup))]

# rename the columns with the cols list.
df.columns=cols

df
```

Output:

```
    blah    blah2   blah3   blah.1  blah.2
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
```

Comment: You should really add some description to your answer by editing it.

Comment: This is great!! it worked for me.. as i had duplicated columns and needed to rename automatically... when pandas read_excel to df.. it can rename automatically the duplicated names... this code is only required... when we manually manipulate the column names ourselves. I hope the code can be indented.. and explained clearly by someone.

Comment: Why would I get `AttributeError: 'slice' object has no attribute 'sum'`? hmmm

Comment: @Lamakaha, Me to same issue... Please help on this

Comment: Not useful for me, all duplicate columns rename at the same time.

Comment: It wasn't working to me because the first two occurrences of a duplicated name were being renamed equal, either as origin, or with .1, or with .2 depending different trials I did with str(d_idx). So I think is a problem with a pointer. Solution of @MaxU worked to me in one line

Answer (score 39):

[Starting with Pandas 0.19.0 `pd.read_csv()` has improved support for duplicate column names](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/whatsnew.html#read-csv-has-improved-support-for-duplicate-column-names)

So we can try to use the internal method:

```
In [137]: pd.io.parsers.ParserBase({'names':df.columns})._maybe_dedup_names(df.columns)
Out[137]: ['blah', 'blah2', 'blah3', 'blah.1', 'blah.2']
```

Since Pandas 1.3.0:

```
pd.io.parsers.base_parser.ParserBase({'names':df.columns, 'usecols':None})._maybe_dedup_names(df.columns)
```

This is the "magic" function:

```
def _maybe_dedup_names(self, names):
    # see gh-7160 and gh-9424: this helps to provide
    # immediate alleviation of the duplicate names
    # issue and appears to be satisfactory to users,
    # but ultimately, not needing to butcher the names
    # would be nice!
    if self.mangle_dupe_cols:
        names = list(names)  # so we can index
        counts = {}

        for i, col in enumerate(names):
            cur_count = counts.get(col, 0)

            if cur_count > 0:
                names[i] = '%s.%d' % (col, cur_count)

            counts[col] = cur_count + 1

    return names
```

Comment: This is create, for others to use it just do:  df.columns = pd.io.parsers.ParserBase({'names':df.columns})._maybe_dedup_names(df.columns)

Comment: The comment by @miguelfg is a great solution if you are not reading from csv. No need to write any function on your own!

Comment: This also works fine with ParserBase({}) because the input to _maybe_dedup_names() is not taken from the class, but given directly as a function argument. You just need to make the constructor's validation checks happy and an empty dict does that. It's probably not any faster but it makes the code less confusing because it's clear where the data is being passed.

Comment: I'm using Pandas 1.5.0 and ParserBase({'usecols': None}) is required. The key, names, is not required.

Comment: In version 1.5.2, ParserBase needs to be imported from `pandas.io.parsers.base_parser`. (I don't know if it was moved to `pandas.io.parsers.base_parser` or is no longer exported from `pandas.io.parsers`.) `{'usecols': None}` still required.

Answer (score 13):

You could use this:

```
def df_column_uniquify(df):
    df_columns = df.columns
    new_columns = []
    for item in df_columns:
        counter = 0
        newitem = item
        while newitem in new_columns:
            counter += 1
            newitem = "{}_{}".format(item, counter)
        new_columns.append(newitem)
    df.columns = new_columns
    return df
```

Then

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*5).reshape(2,5))
df.columns=['blah','blah2','blah3','blah','blah']
```

so that **df**:

```
   blah  blah2  blah3   blah   blah
0     0      1      2      3      4
1     5      6      7      8      9
```

then

```
df = df_column_uniquify(df)
```

so that **df**:

```
   blah  blah2  blah3  blah_1  blah_2
0     0      1      2       3       4
1     5      6      7       8       9
```

Answer (score 4):

You could assign directly to the columns:

```
In [12]:

df.columns = ['blah','blah2','blah3','blah4','blah5']
df
Out[12]:
   blah  blah2  blah3  blah4  blah5
0     0      1      2      3      4
1     5      6      7      8      9

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

If you want to dynamically just rename the duplicate columns then you could do something like the following (code taken from answer 2: [Index of duplicates items in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list)):

```
In [25]:

import collections
dups = collections.defaultdict(list)
dup_indices=[]
col_list=list(df.columns)
for i, e in enumerate(list(df.columns)):
  dups[e].append(i)
for k, v in sorted(dups.items()):
  if len(v) >= 2:
    dup_indices = v

for i in dup_indices:
    col_list[i] = col_list[i] + ' ' + str(i)
col_list
Out[25]:
['blah 0', 'blah2', 'blah3', 'blah 3', 'blah 4']
```

You could then use this to assign back, you could also have a function to generate a unique name that is not present in the columns prior to renaming.

Comment: Or something like `df.columns = ['blah{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,len(df.columns)+1)]`, or `"blah" + pd.Series(range(1,6)).astype(str)`, etc.

Comment: @DSM yes that would work, I was assuming that the OP example was not a real example

Comment: direct assignment of column names doesn't work for me - I don't really want to know where these duplicate columns are located in relation to other columns. I just truly need to rename them. To make my example clearer, say I read in 3 columns with the name 'price' and I know that the first price is open price, second is close price and the third is end of day price so i need to rename them along these lines. There might be a ton of other columns in there and I don't want to know what they are and where all these columns are sitting in relation to each other

Comment: In that case I would just get the columns as a list, find the duplicates, rename those and assign back, you can convert the columns to a list doing `list(df.columns)`, that would be too difficult

Comment: Here is a related post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list so you could use that to get the indices where there are duplicates and then just enumerate a new suffix or whatever, modify the list and assign back

Comment: @EdChum - yes it works but i was looking for something more pandas-like

Comment: Your answer would work, it depends on how you want to rename the duplicates, not sure I can think of a better way

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote this code it uses a list comprehension to update all duplicated names.

```
df.columns = [x[1] if x[1] not in df.columns[:x[0]] else f"{x[1]}_{list(df.columns[:x[0]]).count(x[1])}" for x in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
duplicated_idx = dataset.columns.duplicated()

duplicated = dataset.columns[duplicated_idx].unique()



rename_cols = []

i = 1
for col in dataset.columns:
    if col in duplicated:
        rename_cols.extend([col + '_' + str(i)])
    else:
        rename_cols.extend([col])

dataset.columns = rename_cols
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Please add i+=1 after the if/else in the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Lamakaha for the solution. Your idea gave me a chance to modify it and make it workable in all the cases.

I am using Python 3.7.3 version.

I tried your piece of code on my data set which had only one duplicated column i.e. two columns with same name. Unfortunately, the column names remained As-Is without being renamed. On top of that I got a warning that `"get_duplicates()` is deprecated and same will be removed in future version". I used `duplicated()` coupled with `unique()` in place of `get_duplicates()` which did not yield the expected result.

I have modified your piece of code little bit which is working for me now for my data set as well as in other general cases as well.

Here are the code runs with and without code modification on the example data set mentioned in the question along with results:

---

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*5).reshape(2,5))

df.columns=['blah','blah2','blah3','blah','blah']
df

cols=pd.Series(df.columns)

for dup in df.columns.get_duplicates(): 
    cols[df.columns.get_loc(dup)]=[dup+'.'+str(d_idx) if d_idx!=0 else dup for d_idx in range(df.columns.get_loc(dup).sum())]
df.columns=cols

df
```

> f:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: FutureWarning:
>   'get_duplicates' is deprecated and will be removed in a future
>   release. You can use idx[idx.duplicated()].unique() instead

Output:

```
    blah    blah2   blah3   blah    blah.1
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
```

Two of the three "blah"(s) are not renamed properly.

---

## Modified code

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*5).reshape(2,5))
df.columns=['blah','blah2','blah3','blah','blah']
df

cols=pd.Series(df.columns)

for dup in cols[cols.duplicated()].unique(): 
    cols[cols[cols == dup].index.values.tolist()] = [dup + '.' + str(i) if i != 0 else dup for i in range(sum(cols == dup))]
df.columns=cols

df
```

Output:

```
    blah    blah2   blah3   blah.1  blah.2
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
```

---

Here is a run of modified code on some another example:

```
cols = pd.Series(['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'L', 'M', 'A', 'Y', 'M'])

for dup in cols[cols.duplicated()].unique():
    cols[cols[cols == dup].index.values.tolist()] = [dup + '_' + str(i) if i != 0 else dup for i in range(sum(cols == dup))]

cols

Output:
0       X
1       Y
2       Z
3       A
4       B
5       C
6     A_1
7     A_2
8       L
9       M
10    A_3
11    Y_1
12    M_1
dtype: object
```

Hope this helps anybody who is seeking answer to the aforementioned question.

Answer (score 2):

In Pandas v2.1 you can use the `pd.io.common.dedup_names` function, like:

```py
In [137]: pd.io.common.dedup_names(df.columns, is_potential_multiindex=False)
Out[137]: ['blah', 'blah2', 'blah3', 'blah.1', 'blah.2']
```

The earlier method (`pd.io.parsers.base_parser.ParserBase({'names':df.columns, 'usecols':None})._maybe_dedup_names(df.columns)`) has been removed so no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Since the accepted answer (by Lamakaha) is not working for recent versions of pandas, and because the other suggestions looked a bit clumsy, I worked out my own solution:

```
def dedupIndex(idx, fmt=None, ignoreFirst=True):
    # fmt:          A string format that receives two arguments: 
    #               name and a counter. By default: fmt='%s.%03d'
    # ignoreFirst:  Disable/enable postfixing of first element.
    idx = pd.Series(idx)
    duplicates = idx[idx.duplicated()].unique()
    fmt = '%s.%03d' if fmt is None else fmt
    for name in duplicates:
        dups = idx==name
        ret = [ fmt%(name,i) if (i!=0 or not ignoreFirst) else name
                      for i in range(dups.sum()) ]
        idx.loc[dups] = ret
    return pd.Index(idx)
```

Use the function as follows:

```
df.columns = dedupIndex(df.columns)
# Result: ['blah', 'blah2', 'blah3', 'blah.001', 'blah.002']
df.columns = dedupIndex(df.columns, fmt='%s #%d', ignoreFirst=False)
# Result: ['blah #0', 'blah2', 'blah3', 'blah #1', 'blah #2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that also works for multi-indexes

```
# Take a df and rename duplicate columns by appending number suffixes
def rename_duplicates(df):
    import copy
    new_columns = df.columns.values
    suffix = {key: 2 for key in set(new_columns)}
    dup = pd.Series(new_columns).duplicated()

    if type(df.columns) == pd.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex:
        # Need to be mutable, make it list instead of tuples
        for i in range(len(new_columns)):
            new_columns[i] = list(new_columns[i])
        for ix, item in enumerate(new_columns):
            item_orig = copy.copy(item)
            if dup[ix]:
                for level in range(len(new_columns[ix])):
                    new_columns[ix][level] = new_columns[ix][level] + f"_{suffix[tuple(item_orig)]}"
                suffix[tuple(item_orig)] += 1

        for i in range(len(new_columns)):
            new_columns[i] = tuple(new_columns[i])

        df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_columns)
    # Not a MultiIndex
    else:
        for ix, item in enumerate(new_columns):
            if dup[ix]:
                new_columns[ix] = item + f"_{suffix[item]}"
                suffix[item] += 1
        df.columns = new_columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Created a function with some tests so it should be drop in ready; this is a little different than [Lamakaha's excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686572/906385) since it renames the first appearance of a duplicate column:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Dict, List, Set

import pandas as pd

def rename_duplicate_columns(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Rename column headers to ensure no header names are duplicated.

    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): A dataframe with a single index of columns

    Returns:
        pd.DataFrame: The dataframe with headers renamed; inplace
    """
    if not df.columns.has_duplicates:
        return df
    duplicates: Set[str] = set(df.columns[df.columns.duplicated()].tolist())
    indexes: Dict[str, int] = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    new_cols: List[str] = []
    for col in df.columns:
        if col in duplicates:
            indexes[col] += 1
            new_cols.append(f"{col}.{indexes[col]}")
        else:
            new_cols.append(col)
    df.columns = new_cols
    return df

def test_rename_duplicate_columns():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2]], columns=["a", "b"])
    assert rename_duplicate_columns(df).columns.tolist() == ["a", "b"]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2]], columns=["a", "a"])
    assert rename_duplicate_columns(df).columns.tolist() == ["a.1", "a.2"]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3]], columns=["a", "b", "a"])
    assert rename_duplicate_columns(df).columns.tolist() == ["a.1", "b", "a.2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just assign each column a different name.

Suppoese duplicate column name is like = `[a,b,c,d,d,c]`

Then just create a list of name what you want to assign:

```
C = [a,b,c,d,D1,C1]
df.columns = c
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
cols = []  # for tracking if we alread seen it before
new_cols = []

for col in df.columns:
    cols.append(col)
    count = cols.count(col)
    
    if count > 1:
        new_cols.append(f'{col}_{count}')
    else:
        new_cols.append(col)

df.columns = new_cols
```

Comment: You should add some explanation as to why/how this solution is different from (and/or better than) any of the numerous other answers already posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elegant solution:

Isolate a dataframe with only the repeated columns (looks like it will be a series but it will be a dataframe if >1 column with that name):

```
df1 = df['blah']
```

For each "blah" column, give it a unique number

```
df1.columns = ['blah_' + str(int(x)) for x in range(len(df1.columns))]
```

Isolate a dataframe with all but the repeated columns:

```
df2 = df[[x for x in df.columns if x != 'blah']]
```

Merge back together on indices:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Et voila:

```
   blah_0  blah_1  blah_2  blah2  blah3
0       0       3       4      1      2
1       5       8       9      6      7
```