# Pandas DataFrame.append gives error about plan shapes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to append one DataFrame to the end of another.  The first DataFrame has 100 columns.  The second DataFrame has 30 columns. (The second's columns are a subset of the first's.)  My intention is any column not present in the second will simply be assigned an NA value.

I'm following the example described in the Pandas documentation:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-using-append

The second example shows that if the two DataFrames have different columns, pandas will intelligently fill the missing data with NA.

However, when I try this, I just get: "ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned"

```
    df_a.shape
    Out[27]: (50000, 100)

    df_b.shape
    Out[26]: (414, 30)

    df_all = df_a.append(df_b, ignore_index=True)
```

Can anybody help explain what I may be doing wrong?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't be 100% sure (since you haven't posted much about your data), I came across the same error while using append and it turned out to be that one of the dataframes had duplicated column names. Once I corrected this the error went away.

It is a similar issue discussed in the following two posts: [concatenate dataframes with different column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751916/concatenate-dataframes-with-different-column-ordering/35752538)  and [Pandas concat gives error ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226343/pandas-concat-gives-error-valueerror-plan-shapes-are-not-aligned)

but in the context of pd.concat in those posts (although it seems the issues are the same)