# How to merge data frame into one csv file after using glob?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob

I have tried to work on several csv files using glob, for example:

```
import glob 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

# Read all csv files with same file name in the folder
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('./16_2018-02*.csv'))

for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['Date','RSSI','Data','Code'], 
    index_col=None)

    # Slicing information 
    df["ID"] = df["Data"].str.slice(0,2)
    df["X"] = df["Data"].str.slice(2,4)

    # Save the output data to csv with different name 
    df.to_csv(f'{f[:-4]}-train.csv', index=False)
```

In the end of the code, I used to save each dataframe into a new csv file with different name. Considering now I have so many csv data to work with, I want to concatenate them without first writing into each csv file. How should I do that?

Original dataset first 5 rows:

```
Date                            RSSI    Data                        Code        
2018-02-20T00:00:20.886+09:00   -99 1068ffd703d101ec77f425ea98b201  F2D5    
2018-02-20T00:00:21.904+09:00   -95 103cffbc032901ee77f49dea98b301  F2D5        
2018-02-20T00:00:22.415+09:00   -97 103cffbc032901ee77f49dea98b301  F2D5         
2018-02-20T00:00:46.580+09:00   -96 10fdfda803ff01f477f49dfd98cb03  F2D1        
2018-02-20T00:00:48.593+09:00   -96 101bfed3037401f577f49dfe98cd03  F2D6
```

After:

```
Date                            RSSI    Data                        Code    ID  X   
2018-02-20T00:00:20.886+09:00   -99 1068ffd703d101ec77f425ea98b201  F2D5    16  0.065384    
2018-02-20T00:00:21.904+09:00   -95 103cffbc032901ee77f49dea98b301  F2D5    16  0.065340        
2018-02-20T00:00:22.415+09:00   -97 103cffbc032901ee77f49dea98b301  F2D5    16  0.065340         
2018-02-20T00:00:46.580+09:00   -96 10fdfda803ff01f477f49dfd98cb03  F2D1    16  0.065021    
2018-02-20T00:00:48.593+09:00   -96 101bfed3037401f577f49dfe98cd03  F2D6    16  0.065051
```

Comment: Can you supply a couple sample data sets and what you would want the outcome to look like?

Comment: @IanThompson data sets contains many rows with 4 columns ('Date','RSSI','Data','Code'). In the process I added 2 new columns (ID, X) then all files are saved individually in csv files (e.g from 10 data sets in the folder, it wll be saved to 10 csv output files)...

Comment: @IanThompson ..while now the outcome I would like to have is not several csv files, but one csv files with one header concatenated.

Comment: Can you post what that would look like? For example, what do the first 5 rows of two of the `csv`s look like? Post them in code-formatted text so that we can copy them directly and can get you an answer faster.

Comment: @IanThompson added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code *[for appending all the files to 1 file]*:

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('./16_2018-02*.csv'))
appended_data=[] #create a list
for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['Date','RSSI','Data','Code'], 
    index_col=None)

    # Slicing information 
    df["ID"] = df["Data"].str.slice(0,2)
    df["X"] = df["Data"].str.slice(2,4)
    appended_data.append(df) #append to the list
appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data, axis=1) #concat them together
#remove axis=1 if need to append vertically
```

The appended_data is now a dataframe with all files appended together post which you can export the same to csv/excel.

Comment: I tried with no "axis=1" since I need it to be vertically appended, but got this error: ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned. Trying to figure out why because the no. of columns should be the same.

Comment: @npm check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226343/pandas-concat-gives-error-valueerror-plan-shapes-are-not-aligned

Comment: Instead I tried with smaller dataset and your solution worked, thanks! I might just need to check on each dataset later.