# Pandas merge two dataframes with different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging

I'm surely missing something simple here. Trying to merge two dataframes in pandas that have mostly the same column names, but the right dataframe has some columns that the left doesn't have, and vice versa.

```
>df_may

  id  quantity  attr_1  attr_2
0  1        20       0       1
1  2        23       1       1
2  3        19       1       1
3  4        19       0       0

>df_jun

  id  quantity  attr_1  attr_3
0  5         8       1       0
1  6        13       0       1
2  7        20       1       1
3  8        25       1       1
```

I've tried joining with an outer join:

```
mayjundf = pd.DataFrame.merge(df_may, df_jun, how="outer")
```

But that yields:

```
Left data columns not unique: Index([....
```

I've also specified a single column to join on (`on = "id"`, e.g.), but that duplicates all columns except `id` like `attr_1_x`, `attr_1_y`, which is not ideal. I've also passed the entire list of columns (there are many) to `on`:

```
mayjundf = pd.DataFrame.merge(df_may, df_jun, how="outer", on=list(df_may.columns.values))
```

Which yields:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

What am I missing? I'd like to get a df with all rows appended, and `attr_1`, `attr_2`, `attr_3` populated where possible, NaN where they don't show up. This seems like a pretty typical workflow for data munging, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

I think in this case [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) is what you want:

```
In [12]:

pd.concat([df,df1], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
Out[12]:
   attr_1  attr_2  attr_3  id  quantity
0       0       1     NaN   1        20
1       1       1     NaN   2        23
2       1       1     NaN   3        19
3       0       0     NaN   4        19
4       1     NaN       0   5         8
5       0     NaN       1   6        13
6       1     NaN       1   7        20
7       1     NaN       1   8        25
```

by passing `axis=0` here you are stacking the df's on top of each other which I believe is what you want then producing `NaN` value where they are absent from their respective dfs.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. I got 

pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: I've tried to merge that way three DFs with different columns. Some of columns were added, some lost.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me in my current use case, either. Some columns get dropped.  Seems to be sensitive to which dataframe is the first in the list to be concatenated?  Oddly, running the example from the official concat docs works as advertised regardless of order.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Saved a lot of time in merging 3000+ dataframes! Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer will break [if there are duplicate headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099826/13138364):

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.

For example, here `A` has 3x `trial` columns, which prevents [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[3, 1, 4, 1]], columns=['id', 'trial', 'trial', 'trial'])
#    id  trial  trial  trial
# 0   3      1      4      1

B = pd.DataFrame([[5, 9], [2, 6]], columns=['id', 'trial'])
#    id  trial
# 0   5      9
# 1   2      6

pd.concat([A, B], ignore_index=True)
# InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

To fix this, [deduplicate the column names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43792894/13138364) before [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
parser = pd.io.parsers.base_parser.ParserBase({'usecols': None})

for df in [A, B]:
    df.columns = parser._maybe_dedup_names(df.columns) 

pd.concat([A, B], ignore_index=True)
#    id  trial  trial.1  trial.2
# 0   3      1        4        1
# 1   5      9      NaN      NaN
# 2   2      6      NaN      NaN
```

Or as a one-liner but less readable:

```
pd.concat([df.set_axis(parser._maybe_dedup_names(df.columns), axis=1) for df in [A, B]], ignore_index=True)
```

---

Note that for pandas <1.3.0, use: `parser = pd.io.parsers.ParserBase({})`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today using any of concat, append or merge, and I got around it by adding a helper column sequentially numbered and then doing an outer join

```
helper=1
for i in df1.index:
    df1.loc[i,'helper']=helper
    helper=helper+1
for i in df2.index:
    df2.loc[i,'helper']=helper
    helper=helper+1
df1.merge(df2,on='helper',how='outer')
```

Comment: What didn't work of the accepted answer: `pd.concat([df,df1], axis=0, ignore_index=True)`?

Comment: I arrived at this with  non-unique columns. Consider `a = pd.DataFrame({'d':[1], 'b':[2]}).rename(columns={'b':'d'})` and `b=pd.DataFrame({'d':[4, 6]})` then `pd.concat([a, b], axis=0, ignore_index=True)` would fail. Although some workarounds can be applied, I believe that it is better to resolve the root of the problem to have unique column names (as in my case). Also, I would expect some warning when trying to rename on already existing column name.