# when combining pandas dataframe (concat or append) can I set the default value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Starting from this previous question:
[Pandas merge two dataframes with different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097222/pandas-merge-two-dataframes-with-different-columns)

If I concat two dataframes (A & B) that have some of the same columns, but also have columns that are not present in both, in the resulting dataframe the entries for the columns that are not common to both A & B have a value of NaN.  Is there a way to make these entries have another default value?

I would rather not simply replace NaN after the concat operation as there may be NaN values in the original dataframes that I want to preserve.

Here are two example dataframes:

`hello  world  how  extra
1       2      3    g
5      -666    11   h
13             NaN  i
23      7      29   j`

`extra  you   how
        1.1   31
b      -666   37
c       1.3   41
d       NaN   43
-666    1.7  -666`

If for example the default value for use in the disjoint columns is "W4L" instead of NaN, the desired result would be:

`hello  world  how  extra  you
1       2      3    g      W4L
5      -666    11   h      W4L
13             NaN  i      W4L
23      7      29   j      W4L
W4L     W4L    31          1.1
W4L     W4L    37   b      -666
W4L     W4L    41   c      1.3
W4L     W4L    43   d      NaN
W4L     W4L   -666  -666   1.7`

Comment: Please show what your 2 df's look like you may want to `merge` or `combine_first`

Comment: Please also show your intended result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is 'conform' the indices *before* concatenating both dataframes, and in that step it is possible to define a fill_value:

```
common_columns = df1.columns.union(df2.columns)

df1 = df1.reindex(columns=common_columns, fill_value='W4L')
df2 = df2.reindex(columns=common_columns, fill_value='W4L')

pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

With your example data:

```
In [32]: common_columns = df1.columns.union(df2.columns)

In [34]: df1 = df1.reindex(columns=common_columns, fill_value='4WL')

In [35]: df1
Out[35]:
  extra  hello  how world  you
0     g      1    3     2  W4L
1     h      5   11  -666  W4L
2     i     13  NaN        W4L
3     j     23   29     7  W4L

In [36]: df2 = df2.reindex(columns=common_columns, fill_value='W4L')

In [37]: pd.concat([df1, df2])
Out[37]:
  extra hello  how world  you
0     g     1    3     2  W4L
1     h     5   11  -666  W4L
2     i    13  NaN        W4L
3     j    23   29     7  W4L
0         W4L   31   W4L  1.1
1     b   W4L   37   W4L -666
2     c   W4L   41   W4L  1.3
3     d   W4L   43   W4L  NaN
4  -666   W4L -666   W4L  1.7
```

You can see that the original `NaN`s are preserved.