# How can we Match DataFrame using loops in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python code aiming to match 2 tables `puit_1` and `puit_2` in order to retrieve the identifier id of the table `puit_2` by creating a new column id in the table `puit_1`, if the name of the table `puit_1` equals the table `puit_2` .
below the loop :

```py
puits_sig[id_credo] = pd.series([])
for j in range(len(puits_credo['noms'])):
    id_pcredo = []
    for i in range(len(puits_sig['sigle_puits'])):
        if puits_credo['noms'][j] == puits_credo['noms'][j]:
            if str(puits_sig['sigle_puits'][i]) in puits_credo['noms'][j]:
               id_pcredo.append(puits_credo['ID_Objet'][j]) 
               print(id_pcredo)
puits_sig['id_credo'] = id_pcredo
```

**ValueError : length of values 1 does not match length of index 1212**

This code gives me an error that I couldn't solve (for information, I'm a beginner in programming).

Any help below some extract from tables?
Extract from table 1

| [sigle_puit] | [categorie] |
| --- | --- |
| BNY2D | ACTIF |
| BRM2 | INACTIF |

Extract from table 2

| [Nom] | [ID Object] |
| --- | --- |
| BLY23 | 89231 |
| BRM1 | 12175 |

Comment: Can you provide examples for tables 1 and 2?

Comment: I added excerpts from table 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you're looking for is an inner-merge Pandas operation. What this does is create a new dataframe which has the 'name' column which both `puit_1` and `puit_2` have in common, and all other information which comes from the columns in dataframes 1 and 2.

```
merged_df = puit_1.merge(puit_2, how = 'inner', on = ['name'])
```

See this question for more:
[Merge DataFrames with Matching Values From Two Different Columns - Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175060/merge-dataframes-with-matching-values-from-two-different-columns-pandas)

EDIT: If you want to keep rows which have a name which only exists in one dataframe, you might want to use `how='outer'` in your merge operation