# Concat two dataframes: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to concat 2 dataframes vertically, but I get this error:

> Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

How can I fix it?

df1

```
      TimeStamp  Input     X     Y  Time  Distance  Speed Pressure Tilt_X Tilt_X
  16    79769.0  aaaaa  8898  8438   NaN       NaN    NaN     None   None   None
  17    79784.0  aaaaa  8898  8438  15.0       0.0    0.0     None   None   None
  18    79793.0  aaaaa  8898  8438   9.0       0.0    0.0     None   None   None
  19    79802.0  aaaaa  8898  8438   9.0       0.0    0.0     None   None   None
```

df2

```
      TimeStamp Input     X     Y  Time  Distance  Speed Pressure Tilt_X Tilt_Y
  26    84456.0   bbb  8762  9318   NaN       NaN    NaN        0      0      0
  27    84459.0   bbb  8762  9318   3.0       0.0    0.0     4069  -1397  -1445
  28    84459.0   bbb  8762  9318   0.0       0.0    0.0     4069  -1397  -1445
  29    84464.0   bbb  8762  9318   5.0       0.0    0.0     3944  -1397  -1445
  30    84472.0   bbb  8762  9318   8.0       0.0    0.0     3692  -1397  -1445
  31    84482.0   bbb  8741  9253  10.0       0.6    0.0     3317  -1397  -1445
```

I want to concat to this:

```
      TimeStamp  Input     X     Y  Time  Distance  Speed Pressure Tilt_X Tilt_X
  16    79769.0  aaaaa  8898  8438   NaN       NaN    NaN     None   None   None
  17    79784.0  aaaaa  8898  8438  15.0       0.0    0.0     None   None   None
  18    79793.0  aaaaa  8898  8438   9.0       0.0    0.0     None   None   None
  19    79802.0  aaaaa  8898  8438   9.0       0.0    0.0     None   None   None
  26    84456.0    bbb  8762  9318   NaN       NaN    NaN        0      0      0
  27    84459.0    bbb  8762  9318   3.0       0.0    0.0     4069  -1397  -1445
  28    84459.0    bbb  8762  9318   0.0       0.0    0.0     4069  -1397  -1445
  29    84464.0    bbb  8762  9318   5.0       0.0    0.0     3944  -1397  -1445
  30    84472.0    bbb  8762  9318   8.0       0.0    0.0     3692  -1397  -1445
  31    84482.0    bbb  8741  9253  10.0       0.6    0.0     3317  -1397  -1445
```

But the following code results in `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`:

```
aaaaa_tmp_df = pd.concat([aaaaah_Time_df,
                          aaaaa_input_df,
                          aaaaa_X_df,
                          aaaaa_Y_df,
                          aaaaa_time_df_diff,
                          aaaaa_xy_real_dis_df,
                          aaaaa_speed_df,
                          aaaaa_Pressure_df,
                          aaaaa_TiltX_df,
                          aaaaa_TiltY_df],axis = 1)    
aaaaa_tmp_df.columns=['TimeStamp',
                      'Input',
                      'X',
                      'Y',
                      'Time',
                      'Distance',
                      'Speed',
                      'Pressure',
                      'Tilt_X',
                      'Tilt_X']

bbb_tmp_df = pd.concat([bbb_Time_df,
                        bbb_input_df,
                        bbb_X_df,
                        bbb_Y_df,
                        bbb_time_df_diff,
                        bbb_xy_real_dis_df,
                        bbb_speed_df,
                        bbb_Pressure_df,
                        bbb_TiltX_df,
                        bbb_TiltY_df],axis = 1)    
bbb_tmp_df.columns=['TimeStamp',
                    'Input',
                    'X',
                    'Y',
                    'Time',
                    'Distance',
                    'Speed',
                    'Pressure',
                    'Tilt_X',
                    'Tilt_Y']


aaaaa = aaaaa_tmp_df[aaaaa_tmp_df['Input'] == 'aaaaa']
bbb = bbb_tmp_df[bbb_tmp_df['Input'] == 'bbb']

all_df = pd.concat([aaaaa,bbb],axis = 0, ignore_index=True)
```

Error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\Python\Digiinfo_Parser\Digiinfo_Parser.py", line 276, in 
  <module>
all_df = pd.concat([touch,pen,ptp],axis = 0, ignore_index=True)

File "C:\Users\ANDYCHEN\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 298, in concat
return op.get_result()

File "C:\Users\ANDYCHEN\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 516, in get_result
indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)

File "C:\Users\ANDYCHEN\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3171, in get_indexer
raise InvalidIndexError(

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index 
objects
```

Comment: a `concat` works for me without issue, can you double check your example? Also please provide the exact command you used

Comment: Code has  attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `InvalidIndexError` is actually referring to the **column** index.

`df1` has duplicate column names:

```
... Pressure Tilt_X Tilt_X
```

`pd.concat` does not work with duplicate column names.

In this case it looks like the second `Tilt_X` should actually be `Tilt_Y`, but you should check all of your dataframes' columns to make sure there are no other duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You want to `concat` vertically, but used `axis=1`. Remove this parameter:

```
pd.concat([input_df, time_df, contactid_df, x_df, y_df, pressure_df, tiltx_df, tilty_df])
```

Comment: i want to concat  `all_df = pd.concat([touch,pen,ptp],axis = 0, ignore_index=True)` ,get same error

Comment: please provide the complete error and a **minimal** reproducible example