# how to merge two DF with different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two data frames
df1 - have 5 rows

```
|id|name|age|weight|
|1 |aaaa|16 | 56   |
|2 |bbbb|17 | 60   |
|3 |cccc|18 | 56   |
|4 |dddd|16 | 61   |
|5 |ffff|20 | 75   |
```

df2 - also have 5 rows with same id but not sorted

```
|id|rate|
|5 |0.75|
|1 |0.80|
|3 |0.92|
|4 |0.86|
|2 |0.77|
```

now I need to merge them to be like this
df3

```
|id|name|age|weight|rate|
|1 |aaaa|16 | 56   |0.80|
|2 |bbbb|17 | 60   |0.77|
|3 |cccc|18 | 56   |0.92|
|4 |dddd|16 | 61   |0.86|
|5 |ffff|20 | 75   |0.75|
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas merge two dataframes with different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097222/pandas-merge-two-dataframes-with-different-columns)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a df_1 similar to this:

```
   id name  col1
0   1  foo    42
1   2  bar    43
```

and df_2 similar to this:

```
   id  rate
0   2    -1
1   1     1
```

you can use the `join` method from pandas ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)):

`df_1.join(df_2.set_index("id"), on="id")`
which gives

```
   id name  col1  rate
0   1  foo    42     1
1   2  bar    43    -1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use the merge function using pandas. It'll allow you to specify the the type of join you want to perform on the two dataframes.

```
pd.merge(left = first_dataframe, right = second_dataframe, how = 'specify the type of join here like left, right, inner etc..', on = 'specify the column here')
```

Here's some documentation that you can use to refer the merge function.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge`:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='id')
   id  name  age  weight  rate
0   1  aaaa   16      56  0.80
1   2  bbbb   17      60  0.77
2   3  cccc   18      56  0.92
3   4  dddd   16      61  0.86
4   5  ffff   20      75  0.75
```

Read [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)