# Insert dataframe pandas if columns in one df not exists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i try append one df into two df in pandas, but in one df some columns not exists, how make for him none/na values?
All trouble that sometimes one or more columns may be missed ('ID/addresses/birthDate/etc)

Example for data

```
    employeeID  birthDate   birthplace
df1        123  2020-01-01          LA

     employeeID  addresses   birthDate  Department  
df2        777          NY   2001-12-31         HR
```

Needed

```
 employeeID  addresses   birthDate      birthplace     Department  
        123       None   2020-01-01             LA           None
        777         NY   2001-12-31           None             HR
```

My code

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df_all = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'addresses', 'birthDate', 'birthplace', 'Department'])

count = 0
while count < df["ID"].count():
    m = df[count:count + 1000]
    r = requests.get(
        "example.com/IDs=" + ','.join(m['ID'].astype(str)),
        headers={'Host': 'host'}
    )
    df2 = pd.read_json(StringIO(r.text))
    df2 = pd.json_normalize(df2['data'])

    df_all.loc[count] = df2.get(['ID', 'addresses', 'birthDate', 'birthplace', 'Department'])
    count = count + 1000
else:
    print(f"rows count: {count}")

print(df_all)

cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input instead of `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")`

Comment: Please read [mre]

Comment: It has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097222/pandas-merge-two-dataframes-with-different-columns