# Assign new series to existing column by column index

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace a date column by formatted strings. I can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-01-02'), columns=['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

However, I want to use the column index instead of the column name (the dataframe is passed to me, and I can't guarantee that column names are unique). I can do it like this:

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This works fine, but it fails for a dataframe of length one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01')], columns=['date'])
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

> pandas/core/internals.py in _try_coerce_args(self, values, other)
>
> -> 2265                 other = other.astype('i8', copy=False).view('i8')
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2016-01-01'

Note that the assignment by column name still works:

```
df['date'] = df.iloc[:, 0].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I would like to understand why the assignment by column index fails for a dataframe of length 1, and what I can do to make it work. I use pandas 0.19.1 with python 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hack, but works - select column by position with `[]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01')], columns=['date'])

print (df.columns[0])
date

df[df.columns[0]] = df.iloc[:, 0].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print (df)
         date
0  2016-01-01
```

Comment: Wait, it doesn't solve my problem in the case column names are not unique :(

Comment: Maybe I should just raise an error when column names are not unique. I'd still be curious to know why the assignment fails, though.

Comment: Yes, duplicated columns are problem. But if use last version of pandas `read_csv` solve duplicated columns - add `.1` ...

Comment: I found it - [how rename duplicated column names](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24686572/2901002), I hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful! I will accept your answer tomorrow, just in case someone can explain why the assignment fails in the meantime.

Comment: Sure, no problem. ;) Nice day!