# Python Pandas, convert iloc slice to float

Tags: python, pandas

I use

```
Report.iloc[:,6:] = Report.iloc[:,6:].astype(float)
```

to convert those columns to float.
The problem is, that it doesn´t change Report when used in my code file. But when I use it in the Console it works.

```
Report.iloc[:,6:] = Report.iloc[:,6:].astype(float)
Report.info()
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: I can´t reproduce it with a subset of my data. It only fails with this slice (too big to show here)

Comment: I works now. I use this code now:
Report[columns_to_convert] = Report[columns_to_convert].astype(float)

Comment: Interestingly, I had a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269935/assign-new-series-to-existing-column-by-column-index) recently. It looks like `iloc` does not work very well with data type changes...