# make a list of the variables that contain missing values - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df, which has many missing values.

I would like to find the variables/columns which has missing values.

Tried below code:

```
vars_with_na = [var for var in df.columns if df[var].isnull().sum() > 0]
```

But it is giving below error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggests? That is: `vars_with_na = [var for var in df.columns if df[var].isnull().any()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here error means there are some duplicated columns names, so `df[var]` return `DataFrame`, not `Series`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'a':[np.nan, 1],'b':[1, 1],'c':[np.nan, np.nan]})

df.columns = ['a','a','s']
print (df['a'])
     a  a
0  NaN  1
1  1.0  1
```

---

```
vars_with_na = [var for var in df.columns if df[var].isnull().sum() > 0]
print (vars_with_na)
```

Possible solution is [deduplicated them first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24685012/2901002).