# merge dataframe with the same columns name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Hi i have a dataframe that looks like that :

| Unnamed: 0 | X1 | Unnamed: 1 | X2 | Unnamed: 1 | X3 | Unnamed: 2 | X4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1970-01-31 | 5.0 | 1970-01-31 | 1.0 | 1970-01-31 | 1.0 | 1980-01-30 | 1.0 |
| 1970-02-26 | 6.0 | 1970-02-26 | 3.0 | 1970-02-26 | 3.0 | 1980-02-26 | 3.0 |

I have many columns (631) that looks like that.

I would like to have :

| date | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1970-01-31 | 5.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | na |
| 1970-02-26 | 6.0 | 3.0 | 3.0 | na |
| 1980-01-30 | na | na | na | 1.0 |
| 1980-02-26 | na | na | na | 3.0 |

I tried :

```py
res_df = pd.concat(
    df2[[date, X]].rename(columns={date: "date"}) for date, X in zip(df2.columns[::2], 
    df2.columns[1::2])
    ).pivot_table(index="date")
```

It works for small data but do not work for mine. Maybe because I have the same columns name 'Unnamed: 1' in my df.
I have a message error:

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: where is the data sourced from? you have duplicate column names there. It might be possible to get a cleaner solution, if we can control/influence how the input dataframe is created

Comment: It is from an excel file. I read multiple worksheets with instruction : 
> df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(workbook_url, sheet_name=None, skiprows=[0]), axis=1).droplevel(0, axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

Crete index by `date` varible and use `axis=1` in `concat`:

```
res_df = (pd.concat((df2[[date, X]].set_index(date) 
                     for date, X in zip(df2.columns[::2],  df2.columns[1::2])), axis=1)
            .rename_axis('date')
            .reset_index())
print (res_df)
         date   X1   X2   X3   X4
0  1970-01-31  5.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
1  1970-02-26  6.0  3.0  3.0  NaN
2  1980-01-30  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
3  1980-02-26  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

EDIT: Error seems like duplicated columns names in your DataFrame, possible solution is deduplicated before apply solution above:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','a','b'], index=[0])

#you can test if duplicated columns names
print (df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])
Index(['a', 'a'], dtype='object')

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/43792894/2901002
df.columns = pd.io.parsers.ParserBase({'names':df.columns})._maybe_dedup_names(df.columns)
print (df.columns)
Index(['a', 'a.1', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Still an error which is : ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Comment: It still works when I do not have the same columns name but not where I have the same one !

Comment: @Jacques - Answer was edited.