# Concat List of DataFrames row-wise - throws pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a list `df_l` of ~200 Dataframes, which all have the same number of columns and names.

When I try to run:

`df = pd.concat(df_l, axis=0)`

it throws the error:

> pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely
> valued Index objects

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084071/concat-dataframe-reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-objects) I tried to reset the index of each dataframe, but I'll still get the same error.

```
new_l = [df.reset_index(drop=True) for df in df_l]
pd.concat(new_l, axis=0)
```

Also `pd.concat`arguments like `ignore_index=True` did not help in any combination. Any advice?

Running on `python 3.8` and `pandas 1.4.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is problem with duplicated columns names, here is solution for deduplicate them with [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/44957247/2901002
def df_column_uniquify(df):
    df_columns = df.columns
    new_columns = []
    for item in df_columns:
        counter = 0
        newitem = item
        while newitem in new_columns:
            counter += 1
            newitem = "{}_{}".format(item, counter)
        new_columns.append(newitem)
    df.columns = new_columns
    return df

new_l = [df.pipe(df_column_uniquify).reset_index(drop=True) for df in df_l]
```

Comment: Hi does this require a specifc pandas version? I get `AttributeError: module 'pandas.io.parsers' has no attribute 'ParserBase'` - Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Maeaex1 - I change solution with custom function, now should working.

Comment: Thank you so much! Wish you a merry christmas and an awesome year 2023!